# TypeScript inference of string literals

Tags: typescript

My question is pretty simple. Given this code:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const map01 = array.map((v) => v % 2 ? "" : "");
//    ^? string[]
const map02 = array.map((v) => v % 2 ? "odd" : "even");
//    ^? ("odd" | "even")[]
const map03 = array.map((v) => v % 2 ? "!" : "");
//    ^? ("" | "!")[]
```

Why such odd inference by TypeScript? Shouldn't `map01` be inferred as `""[]`?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgA8lm)

[image]

Comment: Looks like this happens whenever both values are the same. `? "odd" : "odd"` also results in `string[]`

Comment: Given what @CertainPerformance has discovered it's almost certainly a bug in TypeScript (not intended behavior).  I'd file an issue with them to make sure.

Comment: The same behaviour occurs with simple functions that have two different paths  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwBQA8BciwgLYBGApgE4CUiA3iUVCCUuogKSIBMiA-IgEQ+LY+AXwCwAKAD0ExAD1O40JFgJEBDNlyFSFarXqMW7Lr36CAdD1GTpc8eIgIAzlEQREAXkSoAbhvzFyDwA+RG9DDm4+ARMAbnEpRETZeTEHMGdEABMPL18cf21g0PDjKPMeOOsk5LsxRWh4JCIfPy1AynFqmGBc8J1O6qSaOgYTAcShRCIAG0ciKnHB4f0xsWqrKwVwBpVgFvy2-rWk7t7WNiPBob1RvkXJmbmF46vl24t78SEgA

Comment: Or when just a constant `const map04 = array.map(() => "b"); // string[]`. I have a hunch this is the same to the compiler as `(v) => v ? 'b' : 'b'`. But that's a pretty nonsensical ternary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The details for how and when [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) widening happens are laid out in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  In particular, it says:

> - In a function with no return type annotation, if the inferred return type is a literal type (but not a literal union type) and the function does not have a contextual type with a return type that includes literal types, the return type is widened to its widened literal type.

So this implies that in the case of `"odd" | "even"`, you have a literal [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type, which is not widened, while in the case of `""`, you have a non-union literal type, which *is* widened.

As for why this rule is used as opposed to a simpler "never widen" rule, it's a heuristic that was chosen to minimize surprise in "normal" circumstances.  Literal types are generally more useful in unions than standing alone, so the compiler assumes that `function foo() {return "abc"}` is more likely intended to return `string`, while `function bar() {return Math.random<0.5 ? "abc" : "def"}` is more likely intended to return a union of literals.  As a heuristic it's not perfect, but it has apparently caused less surprise than alternatives would.

There are various issues in GitHub where the current behavior is deemed to be working as intended; for example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#51551](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51551) with [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51551#issuecomment-1319058610):

> The widening rules are in place to heuristically attempt to infer "better" types and different code is allowed to behave differently under these heuristics