# Is there a problem with typescript's type inference?

Tags: typescript

Look at the code below

```
const foo = [1,2].map((item) => {

  const logic = item === 1 ? 'not' : 'and'; 
  
  return {
    logic,
  };
});
```

When the mouse is over the 'logic', Its type is 'not'|'and'
But when the mouse hovers over 'foo'
But at this time the type of 'logic' is string

I'm expecting this 'logic' in foo to also be of union type

Comment: Looks quite like [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801723/typescript-inference-of-string-literals) a while back... I think jcalz's answer still applies.

Comment: @zenly Indeed. The key phrase [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) is "we always use literal types for literals and then widen those literal types as appropriate when they are ***inferred** as types for mutable locations*". Here, the returned value can have its `logic` property mutated, so it is widened to `string`. [Minimal example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWxgXhgWQIZQBYB0ATtmACYjIAUAlDADwwAMBArDAPwwBE23MALh4AjbgFgAUAHopMOTAB6HSaEiwAbgEZ0MAN7wkqAL6SZ8xcomroMdQCYd+hChhGY2CDGtRTs+UqA)

Comment: @Minimal  Your answer is what I want, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because the element types of the array are not number literals. They're just numbers. The same applies to the properties of the returned object.

You can handle this in a few different ways, the most convenient of which is to use the `as const` type assertion on the array itself. In short, this assertion tells the compiler to treat every value in the array as a value of const type and as you know from declaring individual variables as const, this results in the inference of literal types.

To learn more about const assertions, see the [typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

```
const foo = ([1,2] as const).map(item => {

  const logic = item === 1 ? 'not' : 'and'; 
  
  return {
    logic,
  } as const;
});
```

Note how we also apply this type of surgeon to the return value of the map callback. The assertion doesn't simply apply to array members but also to the property values of objects, making literal types out of their properties

You can clean this up by extracting a local

```
const values = [1,2] as const;

const foo = values.map(item => {

  const logic = item === 1 ? 'not' : 'and'; 
  
  return {
    logic,
  } as const;
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBeGAKA2gRgDQCYC6MAhhDKJFAJQB0AtkQA6qoCWUAprZTEgHwwBvALAAoUTDLhoMADYgA5i2A8YbTjyQpMMAPwwA5GBBR9MAFwGiYACb6A3DHGOREgE7soAV1dhBTiXKKwE4AvsSk5NCiIZR2oqJAA)

Comment: This is not correct and [the solution doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBtAjAGgEwC6MAhhDKJFAJQB0AtsQA5poCWUApnVSgHwwBvALAAoUTHLhoMADYgA5q2AoY7LimSosMAPwwA5GBBR9MAFwHiYACb6A3DHGOREgE4coAV1dhBTiXKKwE4AvnaiIVR2QA). But it has something to do with const assertions or something alike. The literal types gets lost here `return { logic }`, here `logic` is typed as `string`. Probably because there's nothing to tell TS that this property is not writable/constant/something like that, idk.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBeGAKA2gRgDQCYC6MAhhDKJFAJQB0AtkQA6qoCWUAprZTEgHwwBvALAAoUTDLhoMADYgA5i2A8YbTjyQpMMAPwwA5GBBR9MAFwGiYACb6A3DHGOREgE7soAV1dhBTiXKKwE4AvsSk5NCiIZR2oqJAA

Comment: I thought that I tried that. `return { logic } as const` solves the issue, `([1,2] as const)` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the type to the map callback like:

```js
const foo = [1,2].map((item): {logic: 'not' | 'and' } => {

  const logic = item === 1 ? 'not' : 'and'; 
  
  return {
    logic,
  };
});
```

Comment: This solution does solve the specific problem but it doesn't address the question of why the type inference doesn't work as the op expected